# What is this manga about a demon or vampire linked to an acolyte?

Tags: kai-pilgrim

I read this manga a very long time ago....

And the story goes like this: There's a demon, or vampire or something (can't remember it well) who overpowers all.

He's the strongest, and up until the current state nobody can kill him, because he is somewhat an immortal, because of his healing powers...

He's also cruel. Then this girl came; an acolyte girl that was ordered cast a spell (or prayer) to him, and then to kill herself. She was ordered by the "highest rank priest" (somewhat similar from the position of the paladin in *Ao no Exorcist*). The spell was actually to connect her life to the demon, so whatever happen to the girl or to the demon will also happen to the other... I can't remember it so well, but I think the girl is scared to kill herself. She also wants to know why the priest ordered her to do such a thing (why did the priests want her to die?).

Well, it ends up that they tag along with each other from then.

That was all that I can remember. And that was just the 1st chapter... I remember that during the time I'm reading it online it was turned to be already licensed so I think the manga was dropped, but I still want to know the title of this one.

Does anyone know what this manga is? Thanks in advance. :)

and, NO. It's not zenki. It doesn't have an anime.

Comment: could it be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenki

Comment: did it get serialized in one of the big magazine's ? if so do you remmember which one ?

Answer (score 6):

I just realized it or rather found it out when it updated yesterday. The title of the work is **[Kai Pilgrim](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=70220)**.

Answer (score 0):

I think the manga you are looking for is Chrono Crusade (or Chrno Crusade). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrono_Crusade